# Не могу понять почему сумма прописью не отображается не полностью скрипт на C#

Tags: c#

Не могу понять почему сумма прописью не отображается не полностью 
то есть например 1425 словами прописывается как  одна тысяча четыреста двадцать
последнее число не прописывает. Или может есть у кого то другое решение проблемы,

```
private void tableCell100_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
    string text = Convert.ToString(tableCell53.Text);
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(text);
    //int number = 1258;
    int[] array_int = new int[4];
    string[, ] array_string = new string[4, 3] {
        {
            " миллиард",
            " миллиарда",
            " миллиардов"
        },
        {
            " миллион",
            " миллиона",
            " миллионов"
        },
        {
            " тысяча",
            " тысячи",
            " тысяч"
        },
        {
            "",
            "",
            ""
        }
    };
    array_int[0] = (number - (number % 1000000000)) / 1000000000;
    array_int[1] = ((number % 1000000000) - (number % 1000000)) / 1000000;
    array_int[2] = ((number % 1000000) - (number % 1000)) / 1000;
    array_int[3] = number % 1000;
    string result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (array_int[i] != 0) {
            if (((array_int[i] - (array_int[i] % 100)) / 100) != 0) switch (((array_int[i] - (array_int[i] % 100)) / 100)) {
            case 1:
                result += " сто";
                break;
            case 2:
                result += " двести";
                break;
            case 3:
                result += " триста";
                break;
            case 4:
                result += " четыреста";
                break;
            case 5:
                result += " пятьсот";
                break;
            case 6:
                result += " шестьсот";
                break;
            case 7:
                result += " семьсот";
                break;
            case 8:
                result += " восемьсот";
                break;
            case 9:
                result += " девятьсот";
                break;
            }
            if (((array_int[i] % 100) - ((array_int[i] % 100) % 10)) / 10 != 1) {
                switch (((array_int[i] % 100) - ((array_int[i] % 100) % 10)) / 10) {
                case 2:
                    result += " двадцать";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result += " тридцать";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    result += " сорок";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    result += " пятьдесят";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    result += " шестьдесят";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    result += " семьдесят";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    result += " восемьдесят";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    result += " девяносто";
                    break;
                }
            }
            switch (array_int[i] % 100) {
            case 1:
                if (i == 2) result += " одна";
                else result += " один";
                break;
            case 2:
                if (i == 2) result += " две";
                else result += " два";
                break;
            case 3:
                result += " три";
                break;
            case 4:
                result += " четыре";
                break;
            case 5:
                result += " пять";
                break;
            case 6:
                result += " шесть";
                break;
            case 7:
                result += " семь";
                break;
            case 8:
                result += " восемь";
                break;
            case 9:
                result += " девять";
                break;
            case 10:
                result += " десять";
                break;
            case 11:
                result += " одиннадцать";
                break;
            case 12:
                result += " двенадцать";
                break;
            case 13:
                result += " тринадцать";
                break;
            case 14:
                result += " четырнадцать";
                break;
            case 15:
                result += " пятнадцать";
                break;
            case 16:
                result += " шестнадцать";
                break;
            case 17:
                result += " семнадцать";
                break;
            case 18:
                result += " восемннадцать";
                break;
            case 19:
                result += " девятнадцать";
                break;
            }
            if (array_int[i] % 100 >= 10 && array_int[i] % 100 <= 19) result += " " + array_string[i, 2] + " ";
            else switch (array_int[i] % 100) {
            case 1:
                result += " " + array_string[i, 0] + " ";
                break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                result += " " + array_string[i, 1] + " ";
                break;
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
                result += " " + array_string[i, 2] + " ";
                break;

            }
        }
        tableCell100.Text = "Slownie: " + result + " EUR 00/100";
    }
}
```

Comment: Судя по всему, вы взяли нерабочий код с [темы форума](https://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread1376104.html). Там же есть отличная ссылка на библиотеку и ее упрощенный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел проблему
может кому то понадобится

```
private void tableCell100_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {


        string text = Convert.ToString(tableCell53.Text);
           // int number = Convert.ToInt32(text);
        int number = 125858;
            int[] array_int = new int[4];
           string[,] array_string = new string[4, 3] {{" миллиард", " миллиарда", " миллиардов"},
                {" миллион", " миллиона", " миллионов"},
                {" тысяча", " тысячи", " тысяч"},
                {"", "", ""}};
            array_int[0] = (number - (number % 1000000000)) / 1000000000;
            array_int[1] = ((number % 1000000000) - (number % 1000000)) / 1000000;
            array_int[2] = ((number % 1000000) - (number % 1000)) / 1000;
            array_int[3] = number % 1000;
            string result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (array_int[i] != 0)
                {
                    if (((array_int[i] - (array_int[i] % 100)) / 100) != 0)
                        switch (((array_int[i] - (array_int[i] % 100)) / 100))
                        {
                            case 1: result += " сто"; break;
                            case 2: result += " двести"; break;
                            case 3: result += " триста"; break;
                            case 4: result += " четыреста"; break;
                            case 5: result += " пятьсот"; break;
                            case 6: result += " шестьсот"; break;
                            case 7: result += " семьсот"; break;
                            case 8: result += " восемьсот"; break;
                            case 9: result += " девятьсот"; break;
                        }
                    if (((array_int[i] % 100) - ((array_int[i] % 100) % 10)) / 10 != 1)
                    {
                        switch (((array_int[i] % 100) - ((array_int[i] % 100) % 10)) / 10)
                        {
                            case 2: result += " двадцать"; break;
                            case 3: result += " тридцать"; break;
                            case 4: result += " сорок"; break;
                            case 5: result += " пятьдесят"; break;
                            case 6: result += " шестьдесят"; break;
                            case 7: result += " семьдесят"; break;
                            case 8: result += " восемьдесят"; break;
                            case 9: result += " девяносто"; break;
                        }
                    }
                    switch (array_int[i] % 10)
                    {
                        case 1: if (i == 2) result += " одна"; else result += " один"; break;
                        case 2: if (i == 2) result += " две"; else result += " два"; break;
                        case 3: result += " три"; break;
                        case 4: result += " четыре"; break;
                        case 5: result += " пять"; break;
                        case 6: result += " шесть"; break;
                        case 7: result += " семь"; break;
                        case 8: result += " восемь"; break;
                        case 9: result += " девять"; break;
                    }
                }
                else switch (array_int[i] % 100)
                    {
                        case 10: result += " десять"; break;
                        case 11: result += " одиннадцать"; break;
                        case 12: result += " двенадцать"; break;
                        case 13: result += " тринадцать"; break;
                        case 14: result += " четырнадцать"; break;
                        case 15: result += " пятнадцать"; break;
                        case 16: result += " шестнадцать"; break;
                        case 17: result += " семнадцать"; break;
                        case 18: result += " восемннадцать"; break;
                        case 19: result += " девятнадцать"; break;
                    }
                if (array_int[i] % 100 >= 10 && array_int[i] % 100 <= 19) result += " " + array_string[i, 2] + " ";
                else switch (array_int[i] % 10)
                    {
                        case 1: result += " " + array_string[i, 0] + " "; break;
                        case 2:
                        case 3:
                        case 4: result += " " + array_string[i, 1] + " "; break;
                        case 5:
                        case 6:
                        case 7:
                        case 8:
                        case 9: result += " " + array_string[i, 2] + " "; break;
                    }
            }                tableCell100.Text="Slownie: "+result + " EUR 00/100";
            }
```